# UITableView in UIViewController auto scroll possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, keyboard, uitextview

I have `UITextView` in `UITableView` and I want to scroll the `UITableView` to make `UITextView` visible. Now I have seen different solutions for this including [**Apple's**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html). But in my case, the cell's height is dynamic. And the `UITextView` may be anywhere in the cell. This way `UITableViewScrollPosition` won't work for me as I have already tried with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`.
Is there a possible precise solution for this OR for that matter is it possible to auto scroll `UITableView` when keyboard appears (shouldn't be [**third party**](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)).

Comment: wat do u mean by autoscroll ?

Comment: @Mr.T : Once keyboard appears on tapping UITextView, which is in UITableView, UITableView should autoscroll or not depending on the position of UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have an Array for paste data to show which named `tableArray`. In viewDidLoad, you need to find your UITextView object index in that array like that;

```
let tableArray = ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "UITextViewObject", "Data5"]
let indexForSearch: Int?
for k in (0...tableArray.count) {
    if tableArray[k] is UITextView {
        indexForSearch = k
        break
    }
}
```

Then scroll your tableview that index programmaticaly;

```
yourTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: indexForSearch, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: As I have mentioned that I already tried with scrollToRowAtIndexPath but it won't work because .Bottom will always move to the bottom of the UITableViewCell. And the cell can be very high with UITextView anywhere in it.